# How to add rule to outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I want to add a single rule that puts all messages from a specific address or to a specific address in a folder.  I can't use the domain because it pacbell.net and I don't want everyone I receive or send an email message to in that domain to end up in the folder

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Apply the rule on messages I receive.
2. From *people or public group* (type required sender address(es)).
3. Move it to the *specified* folder (select the required Outlook folder) and stop processing more rules.
4. No exceptions.
5. Name the rule and save it.

Now copy this rule and change condition to:

2. Sent to *people or public group* (type required recipient address(es)).

These two rules give you *OR*.

Comment: So you can't do it with a single rule

Comment: Exactly. Several conditions in a single rule lead to the AND result. Multiple rules create OR.